# Search certain files only

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 is it possible to search within a certain file type only? 
I want to search just my cs code and exclude .aspx files and VS generated code from datasets and edmx files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `Find in Files` and fill out your search string in `Find What:` and expand Find options and fill out `Look at these file types:` with `*.cs`.

[image]

Comment: I figured it could be done but i never saw that menu. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under Find and Replace/Find in Files (Ctrl+Shift+F), expand "Find options", then you'll notice a box called "look at these file types".  Enter "*.cs" in there, and it'll only look at files with the .cs extension.

Answer (score 1):

For more information, you may refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dechx2tz.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Find in Files search.

You can specify the extensions of the files you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Find in Files" dialog, there is a 'Look in these file types' option, under 'Find Options'